# How do I access the element title in the Json?

Tags: javascript, json, getjson

I want to GET JSON from `http://omadbapi.com/?s=` for search script, but I'm having trouble with get Title element in this JSON:

```
{
    "Search": [{
        "Title": "Sherlock Holmes: A Game of Shadows",
        "Year": "2011",
        "imdbID": "tt1515091",
        "Type": "movie"
    },{
        "Title": "Spy Kids 3-D: Game Over",
        "Year": "2003",
        "imdbID": "tt0338459",
        "Type": "movie"
    }]
}
```

JavaScript :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?',
        mode = 's=',
        input,
        movieName;

    $('button').click(function() {
        var input = $('#movie').val(),
        movieName = encodeURI(input);

        $.getJSON( url + mode + input, function( data ) {
            $.each(data, function(e, p) {
                document.getElementById("item").innerHTML="Title : " + p.Title;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

How can I retrieve `p.Title` or `data.Title` from the returned JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
$.each(data.Search, function(e,p) {
  document.getElementById("item").innerHTML="Title : " + p.Title;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first title:

```
data.Search[0].Title
```

For the second:

```
data.Search[1].Title
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dgrundel/d2m8z3oj/